# Can the changes feed be limited to changes within a specific collection?

Tags: google-docs-api

I've been pouring over the new documentation for the Google Docs API for more efficient ways to synchronize my application's resources and I came upon the changes feed. So far, all the documentation leads me to believe that the changes feed applies to the entire documents list only without the ability to inquire about changes to a specific collection. My application doesn't care about any documents besides the ones belonging to the collections the user has specified. Does anyone know if querying a specific collection for a changes feed is possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, but the nature of the changes feed is such that it should be cheaper to grab just the latest few changes, by [storing the largest timestamp](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_all_changes_since_a_given_changestamp). Once you have the changes feed, you can filter them by looking at the entry's #parent link, that looks like:

```
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#parent'
      type='application/atom+xml'      
      href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A0B343'
      title='Some API Documentation' />
```